# How to implement viewPager in Notification

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-notifications, android-remoteview

I want to know is there a way to implement `ViewPager` in notification remoteViews or a functionality similar to that.

What i want is scrollable images in remoteViews notification like viewpager. I already tried viewpager but it didnt work

Comment: i am not on my development machine now i will post code as soon as i on development machine

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager is not allowed inside RemoteViews. [See the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).

You could use ViewFlipper, but I dont see a way of using it in the expanded BigStyle mode for notifications...still looking for a way to do this.

Comment: some apps provide carousal notification allowing user to swipe images let or right. have you found any way yet? i also need to implement it. I could add image to the view flipper but dont know how to start the animation or how to enable swipe gesture in notification